# USB-C port circuit design: ESD, filtering, short-circuit protection

Tags: usb, filter, usb-device, esd

Below is my first attempt at designing a USB port for a microcontroller board. I am seeking feedback as well as answers to a few specific questions.

[image: schematic of USB-C port]

**Project Parameters**

- USB bus powered device (dongle style, no metal chassis)
- USB 2.0 using a USB-C connector

**Logic of the circuit (from left to right)**

1. The USB-C receptacle is straightforward. Note that the shield has a separate ground from the signal ground, connected by R7 and C5 in parallel, because my MCU vendor’s eval board does it this way.
2. The ESD suppression chip USBLC6-2SC6 ([datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/usblc6-2.pdf)) will be located closest to the USB connector. It has two goals: to protect the device from ESD during plug-in or static electricity, and to protect the host PC’s USB port from damage due to over-voltage events on the device.
3. Pi filter. This is a straightforward power filter.  C4 is a wet Al electrolytic whose ESR should dampen any resonance from the LC filter.
4. Over-current fuse. This is a 500 mA PTC ([datasheet](https://www.belfuse.com/resources/datasheets/circuitprotection/ds-cp-0zcj-series.pdf)) that is guaranteed to trip within 100 ms of 1 A draw at room temperature. Its purpose is that if there is a short in my board somewhere, I will not fry the host PC’s USB port by trying to draw infinite current.

**Specific Questions**

1. I am concerned about permanently damaging the host PC’s USB ports if one of my PCBs malfunctions, e.g. contains a solder bridge short. Will the ESD chip (for overvoltage) combined with the PTC (for overcurrent) be enough to protect the host PC's USB ports from permanent damage in any reasonable scenario?
2. Is a PTC the best way to protect against over-current events?
3. My understanding is that USB ESD chips like the one I’m using are always “unidirectional” devices because USB voltages are always > GND potential.  Does this mean that a high negative voltage transient would not be clamped at all by this ESD chip and could flow right into my circuit and/or right into the host PC?

EDIT:  Shortened and simplified question in hopes of getting more replies.

Comment: Is this a bus powered device (as opposed to a device with its own power supply)?

Comment: If “PWR_FLAG” on the left is connected to “PWR_FLAG” on the right; you short circuit (bypass) your filter and fuse, right? Or are they just Test Points?

Comment: @Codo Yes, it's bus powered.  There is no external power supply.

Comment: @Tyler PWR_FLAG is a quirk of how Kicad, the EDA software I am using, does electrical rules check.  It doesn't correspond to anything real on the board like a test point.  Current flows from left to right in the image above and eventually returns to ground at a voltage regulator + microcontroller circuit that's not shown.

Comment: Since it is a bus-powered device, the host can turn off the power if the device draws excessive current. Most PCs and laptops can and will do it. So I wouldn't be too concerned about it. The PTC looks ok to me.

Comment: @Codo I agree with you.  I just hate to rely on only a single protection mechanism for the host USB ports, since a full PC is expensive to replace.  That's why I sought to add additional protection with the PTC.  Appreciate your saying it looks ok.